# Unable to get request body in flask api using request.form from axios request

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios, request.form

I have written a flask api which recieves post request params using request.form. API performs perfectly in postman but fails in axios request.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way.I hope it will helps you.

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/user/12345',
      data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
      }
    });
```

Comment: Of course I have tried this. It doesn't help.